# Start a shell program in it's own process

Tags: python-3.x

On linux I need to start a number of socat instances from within a Python 3 program.
It appears that the os.exec functions all assume that the program specified in the exec is to replace the currently executing python.

It appears that there are ways to start things as subprocesses but presumably the subprocesses would die when the invoking python program ends.

How do I start several tasks that will persist after my Python program finishes it's work without having my Python process replaced?

Comment: Why do you think the subprocess would die when the invoking python program ends?

Comment: Maybe my assumption was wrong - I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should work

```
bashcmd='echo "1"'
os.popen('/bin/bash -c "'+bashcmd+'"')
```